# Move Files Based on Segements of Filename

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a script to move old PDFs into an archive folder from their source folder.

I have organize ~15,000 PDFs into a series of folders based on their numerical name. The next challenge is that there are multiple revisions of the same file, IE:

```
27850_rev0.pdf
27850_rev1.pdf
27850_rev2.pdf
```

What is the best approach to keeping the highest rev number in the source folder and moving all lower revisions to an archive?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGElf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression with `Group-Object` to isolate all the files that start with that root filename, i.e. 27850*. If you then sort those files you know the last one is the highest revision number:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\06-11-21' -Filter *.txt |
Group-Object -Property { $_.Name.Split('_')[0] } |
ForEach-Object{
    $_.Group | Sort-Object Name | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 |
    Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\temp\06-11-21_backup'    
}
```

I used a few text files in this example, but it should work just the same.

Note: Obviously you'll have to change the folders and filters...

`Group-Object` returns GroupInfo objects, so to get the group of original object I reference `$_.Groups`.

This does depend on the naming format being static. If you have underscores elsewhere in file names we'll likely have a problem.  However, we can always adjust the expression.

Comment: Thanks Steven. The naming is pretty uniform for these files: XXXXX_revXX so it should work. I'll give it a try this weekend and let you know.

Comment: No problem.  When you are ready please consider accepting the answer.  I only mention because you're a newcomer, but it also helps other people find solutions etc...  Thanks!